# Searching a query in Linkedin using the search bar? I'm using Selenium (in python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I'm trying to use selenium to search a company name on LinkedIn, but it seems like the search bar has a bunch of elements overlayed on top of each other. Every id or class I try to use, I get the error: "AttributeError". Could someone guide me which id or class to use? I'd really appreciate it!

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')


username = 'xxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxxx'


nameidElem = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
nameidElem.send_keys(username)
pwdidElem = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
pwdidElem.send_keys(password)
continueElem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn__primary--large")
result = continueElem.submit()
time.sleep(5)


search = driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search-artdeco-typeahead").click()
search.send_keys('sports')
search.submit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Consider using [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to ensure that the elements are present/visible/clickable prior to interacting with them. Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more details
2. When you click the element it might change its state in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) therefore you might need to call [find_element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) function once again
3. You might want to change your locator to match the following element instead:

   ```
   <input role="combobox" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Search" placeholder="Search" type="text">
   ```
4. Putting everything together:

   ```
   nameidElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
   nameidElem.send_keys(username)
   pwdidElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
   pwdidElem.send_keys(password)
   continueElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn__primary--large")))
   result = continueElem.submit()

   search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']"))).click()
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']"))).send_keys('sports')
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']"))).submit()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try with following steps on the search input,

```
search = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Search']").click()
search.send_keys('sports')
search.submit()
```

Comment: Alternative for css selector -> `input[aria-label='Search']`